# Sideway tables flipping back and forth

Tags: positioning, rotating

I'm joining my papers for my thesis and face an issue with sideways tables. I have several sideways tables. In each separate paper, they are fine, always top on the left.
When I put the papers together as chapters in my thesis, the tables just alternately turn 180 degrees (top on the left, then top on the right,...). Any explanation and solution?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the user guide of the [rotating](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/rotating) package, which provides the environments `sidewaysfigure` and `sidewaystable`:

> If the `twoside` option has been given to the main document class (either
>   explicitly, or implicitly as in the default for `book` class), the package will rotate
>   sideways figures [and tables] according to the page number (this requires at least two passes
>   through LATEX). If you want the `twoside` option, but want the figures [and tables] always in
>   one direction, use the `figuresright` or `figuresleft` options to the package.

(added `[and tables]` twice)

I'm surmising that you prefer the outcome generated by the option `figuresright`.

Comment: That simply works. Perfect. Thanks! And yes, I need the 'figuresright'.